# OneDrive iOS SDK - Search API Query parameter doesn't have OR operator ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

I was using Search API to fetch files. I wanted fetch specific type of files and get children API is time consuming and I have to recursively crawl through the folders.

Anything I can use to query such as query = 'abc OR xyz' which would return me file names having 'abc' or 'xyz'. As I currently this is not possible for now.

Current Code

```
NSString *itemId = @"root";
ODItemSearchRequest *req = [[[self.client.drive items:itemId] searchWithQ:@"abc"] request];
[req executeWithCompletion:^(ODCollection *response, ODItemSearchRequest *nextRequest, NSError *error) {
      // returns files containing filename, metadata, and file content 'abc'
}];
```

What I want from API is something like query string accepting **'abc' OR 'xyz**'

```
ODItemSearchRequest *req = [[[self.client.drive items:itemId] searchWithQ:@"'abc' OR 'xyz'"] request];
[req executeWithCompletion:^(ODCollection *response, ODItemSearchRequest *nextRequest, NSError *error) {
      // returns files containing filename, metadata, and file content 'abc' Or 'xyz'
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify query string "abc%20xyz", it should be returning files containing either 'abc' or 'xyz'.

Comment: I tried setting query as "abc%20xyz" and results are wrong. When I just tried query as 'abc' it gave more results than when i used 'abc%20xyz'